# How to set home Button icon image different from launcher icon

Tags: android

I have created an application and setup launcher icon but same icon image is coming for my home button icon also. How can i change it.

Comment: Read the comment on the right side regarding android:logo https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Logo

Answer (score 4):

You can add an extra parameter android:logo in your manifest file. Please see the code below.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/mylogo"
```

It will definitely change your home icon!!